# Multiple files process with different output names in R

Tags: r, dynamic, filenames

I have a number data set (say 50 files) of csv files: crasha, crashabd, crashd, …
I wrote a function to do some changes and analysis for a single data. I want to have a dynamic name for output. For example, I want to have newcrasha, newcrashabd, newcrashd, and … as output csv files. Indeed, I want to get names of imported files and use these as output filenames?
For example:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "D:/health/car crash/", pattern = "csv",full.names = TRUE)

analyze <- function(filename) {

  # Input is character string of a csv file.
  crash <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)

    #merg and summation (crashcounter and NUMBER_INJURED)

newcrash<-crash %>% group_by(COLLISION_DATE) %>% summarise(crashcounter = sum(crashcounter), NUMBER_INJURED = sum(NUMBER_INJURED))
   write.csv( newcrash, "D://health//car crash// newcrash.csv", row.names = FALSE)
 }
filenames <- filenames[1:50]
for (f in filenames) {
  analyze(f)
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: You can use `lapply` on your `filenames`, then its just a matter of parsing and dealing with the filename for saving your new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, following the suggestion of @mhovd:

```
filename <- list.files(path = "D:/health/car crash/", pattern = "csv",full.names = TRUE)

analyze <- function(filename) {
  
  # Input is character string of a csv file.
  crash <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)
  
  #merg and summation (crashcounter and NUMBER_INJURED)
  newcrash<-crash %>% group_by(COLLISION_DATE) %>% summarise(crashcounter = sum(crashcounter), NUMBER_INJURED = sum(NUMBER_INJURED))
  new.name <- paste0("D:/health/car crash/new",basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)),".csv")
  write.csv( newcrash, file=new.name, row.names = FALSE)
}

lapply(filename[1:50], analyze)
```

Comment: Thank you, Elia, I received following error:   Error in paste0(, "D:/health/car crash/new",  : 
  argument is missing, with no default .

Comment: It is noteworthy that I changed "filnames" to "filename" at the first line.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I left an extra comma in `paste0(...)`. I've edited my answer and change also "filenames" to "filename"